# how to re-use last vi command

Tags: vim, vi

How does one re-use a just-executed command in vim?

For example, I open a file with:

```
vi myTestFile
```

Then in normal mode, I search for a word using:

```
/mysearchword\c <Enter>
```

Now I want to search for another similar but slightly different word. But this requires me to type the whole thing again:

```
/mysearchword_1\c <Enter>
```

It would have been much easier if I could just edit the current command that was just executed, and append "_1" to it rather than typing the whole thing again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up arrow works similar as in command line terminal. In your example, just type `/` and then up arrow. It will place your previous search command in the Vim's command line. It works with `:` started commands as well. Moreover, you can use up and down arrows to browse in your commands history.

Note, that this feature requires Vim to work nocompatible mode. Make sure, you have line

```
set nocompatible
```

at the beginning of you `~/.vimrc` file - it must be the first instruction, before all others.

If you don't have `~/.vimrc` (it is not created by default), just create one:

`$ vim ~/.vimrc`

edit as needed and save it.

Comment: up arrow has no effect for me.

Comment: @faizal please read carefuly. You must first type / or : (depending on command type you want to repeat) and then up arrow.

Comment: It works with me. @faizal are you on `vim` or `vi`? Which version? `vi -v`.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki yes, that does not work for me. @Alaa Ali i am using the default `vi` available with Ubuntu 14.04. `vi -v` shows me VIM version 7.4.52. It also shows "Running in Vi compatible mode".

Comment: @AlaaAli good point, I am going to edit my answer to include it.

Comment: It works for me on vim 7.4.52.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki thanks that worked. the compatibility mode was the problem. I used `:set nocp` command in the editor to exit the compatibility mode. I could not find the `~/.vimrc` file as mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @faizal please see my edited answer.

Comment: Instead, i did `sudo apt-get install vim` as i started realizing lots of vim features are missing on my system, like the `vimtutor` and `:help`. The `vi` command was probably starting `vim.tiny`, which comes in Ubuntu by default and has a minimal feature set. Now, after the `vim` installation, i can use the `vim` command and it runs automatically without compatibility mode. `~/.vimrc` still does not exist, but the problem is resolved.